# Priority queue, overloading less operation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I have declared std::priority_queue like this.

```
priority_queue < Aircraft, vector<Aircraft>, less<Aircraft> > *q;
```

And I overloaded the less operator like this.

```
bool Aircraft::operator<(const Aircraft &rhs) const
{
    return (m_dep_time < rhs.m_dep_time);
}
```

I printed out the priority queue and I was getting element in decreasing order (the largest dep_time first). I had to change `m_dep_time < rhs.m_dep_time` to `m_dep_time > rhs.m_dep_time` and it worked. I was able to get the lowest dep_time as I intended.

I thought in logically using `m_dep_time < rhs.m_dep_time` was right instead of `m_dep_time > rhs.m_dep_time` to get an element from the queue in increasing order, the lowest value first.

Could you explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). By default, the top element is the largest element. If you want opposite behavior, you must use different comparison function, just as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` in the queue describes the less-relationship *on the priority*.  So if you want the element with the lowest time value to be the first (highest priority), you will have to compare the time as `m_dep_time > rhs.m_dep_time`

Answer (score 0):

[Priority queues are designed such that its first element is always the **greatest** of the elements it contains.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/)